# android- how to play video in VideoView?

Tags: android, video

I want to play video in a `VideoView`. which one is correct?

```
        video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            video.start();
        }
    });
```

or simply:

```
video.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both method is right to play video but [setOnPreparedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html) is useful when you want to show ProgressBar when media is loading for play from SDCARD,webserver or streaming urls.

and if `video.start();` called without `setOnPreparedListener` some delay occur during loading file then only black screen appear to user until video start.